# Shell script backup routers

Tags: networking, command-line, backup, scripts

Below is a script I've wrote to backup my routers and adsl modem, Any ideas to compact this script in less lines?

Each router have a different kind of structure as you can see.

```
#!/bin/sh
http_txt="10.0.0.59"
cgi="10.0.0.60"
http="10.0.0.66"
date="$(date +%d-%m-%y)"
dest="/home/yamash/"
archive_file="$dest$date.tgz"
local="$dest$date"
login="admin"
pass="PASSWORD"

mkdir $local
cd "$local"
echo "Iniciando Backup"

for http_txt_for in $http_txt; do
    echo "$http_txt_for"
    wget --auth-no-challenge --user=$login --password=$pass $http_txt_for/config.dat -O $http_txt_for.dat
done

for cgi_for in $cgi; do
    echo "$cgi_for"
    wget --user=$login --password=$pass $cgi_for/cgi-bin/export_settings.cgi -O $cgi_for.dat
done

for http_for in $http; do
    echo "$http_for"
    wget --user=$login --password=$pass $http_for/rom-0 -O $http_for
done

cd ..
tar czf $archive_file $local
#rm -R $archive_file $local
echo "Backup Finalizado"
```

Comment: This should probably be on [CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm sorry for posting in wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- You don't need to loop if the variable only has a single value.
- Use verbose mode instead of `echo`ing debug information. `echo`s like this are like comments: They aren't code and they may get obsolete. Printing what's *actually* going on is much more useful for debugging.
- You can use `wget --output-document=/path/to/file` to avoid `cd`ing before `wget`ting.
- You can use `tar -C ..` to go to the parent directory before doing the `tar` operation without `cd`.
- Why create a directory *and* a file name with the date? You only need a date indicator in the tarball name. The canonical solution for this sort of thing is to

  ```
  tmp="$(mktemp -d)"
  trap -- 'rm -frv -- "$tmp"' EXIT
  cd -- "$tmp"
  ```

  and store the temporary files there. This also removes the need for the previous two tips.
- If you only need the date once, you can inline `$date`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will edit my script and after I will post it in main topic, The Ip was a example, I will use more than one IP for variable.